# How do I do coffeescript or= correctly?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, operators, dom-manipulation

What I want to do is simultaneously get a list of items, hide them and assign them to a variable like this:

```
jQuery ->
    client_list or= $('.client-list').find('.actions').hide()
```

But this breaks and ActionController says `Error: the variable "client_list" can't be assigned with ||= because it has not been defined.`

How do I fix this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why do you need the `||=` operator if the variable hasn't been defined? Why can't you just assign?

Comment: cause that would be two lines - I can do it in two lines - wanted to do it in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would do it in coffeescript is like this:

```
client_list = client_list ? $('.client-list').find('.actions').hide()
```

But I see no point in doing this except you'd reuse that call later in runtime (as in lazy loading).

So in fact there should be no need to use `?` at all in this case.